# Drawing multiple sprites in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx, sprite

I am using libgdx 1.2.0 + eclipse.
I want to draw multiple sprites from a class in my game screen, but only one sprite gets drawn.
This is my render method

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(100/255f, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    if(Gdx.input.justTouched()){
        touchX = Gdx.input.getX();
        touchY = Gdx.input.getY();
        //for(int i=0; i < enemy.length; i++)
            //System.out.println(enemy[i].x + " " + enemy[i].y);
    }

    for(int i=0; i< enemy.length; i++){
        enemy[i].update(delta);

        if(enemy[i].getSprite().getBoundingRectangle().contains(touchX/ppX, touchY/ppY))
            enemy[i].reset();

        if(enemy[i].gameOver){
            gameOver = true;
            //System.out.println("Over");
        }

    }

    game.batch.begin();

    //if(!gameOver){
        for(int i=0; i < enemy.length; i++)
            enemy[i].getSprite().draw(game.batch);
    //}

    game.batch.end();

}
```

Same thing happens if I call

```
enemy[0].getSprite().draw(game.batch);
enemy[1].getSprite().draw(game.batch);
```

It always draws something if I call just one of them.

This is the Enemy class. I load the same sprite from the game screen class in every instance of Enemy, but I change it's position.

```
public class Enemy {

private final float minX=1, minY=2;
private final float maxX=31, maxY=18;

private float x,y;
private float time;

private Sprite sprite;

boolean gameOver;

public Enemy(Sprite sprite){
    this.sprite = sprite;
    reset();
}

public Sprite getSprite(){
    return sprite;
}

public void reset(){
    x = minX + (int)(Math.random() * (maxX - minX + 1));
    y = minY + (int)(Math.random() * (maxY - minY + 1));
    time = 0.0f;
    gameOver = false;
    sprite.setPosition(x, y);
}

public void update(float delta){
    time += delta;
    if(time >= 3.0f)
        gameOver = true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I load the same sprite from the game screen class in every instance of
>   Enemy, but I change it's position.

It's the problem, you must create a `new Sprite()` for each `Enemy` object. However, when you change the sprite position of an enemy, the position of all the enemies are changed.

[image: side effect]

As you can see, you will reach the same sprite doing `enemy[0].getSprite()` or `enemy[1].getSprite()`. You can easily check this with the reference equality `enemy[0].getSprite()==enemy[1].getSprite()`.

You can solve this issue with something like

```
public Enemy(Sprite sprite){
    this.sprite = new Sprite(sprite);
    reset();
}
```

Another strange thing in your code :

```
public void reset(){
    x = minX + (int)(Math.random() * (maxX - minX + 1));
    y = minY + (int)(Math.random() * (maxY - minY + 1));
    time = 0.0f;
    gameOver = false;
    sprite.setPosition(x, y);
}
```

If you do `sprite.setPosition(x, y)`, then modifying `x` and `y` is not enough to change the sprite's position. You should improve your `update(float delta)` method in this way, to ensure the sprite's position is correctly updated.

```
public void update(float delta){
    time += delta;
    if(time >= 3.0f)
        gameOver = true;
    sprite.setPosition(x, y);
}
```

Comment: The change in `Enemy` class constructor solved my problem. Why is it necessary to change my sprite's position in the `update(fload delta)` method? `x` and `y` are modified only in the `reset()` method.

Comment: @96andrei Actually, it's necessary to change the sprite's position during the `update(float delta)` only if your enemies move :)